# Given this table, find the best approximation of this function using least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation, least-squares

I am at the end of my ropes trying to get this question correct. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

---

"The table below lists the height h (in cm), the age a (in years), the gender g (0 = "Female", 1 = "Male"), and the weight w (in kg) of some college students.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 \text{Height} & \text{Age} & \text{Gender} & 
 \text{Weight}\\ \hline
 155 & 21 & 0 & 47 \\ \hline
 173 & 19 & 1 & 68 \\ \hline
 175 & 20 & 1 & 70 \\ \hline
 180 & 21 & 1 & 77 \\ \hline
 160 & 22 & 0 & 52 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We need to fit a linear function of the form: w = c<sub>0</sub> + c<sub>1</sub>h + c<sub>2</sub>a + c<sub>3</sub>g.

Find the best approximation of this function, using least squares"

---

We need to solve for the normal equation A<sup>T</sup>Ac = A<sup>T</sup>B.

So I set up my two matrices as:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 155 & 21 & 0\\
1 & 173 & 19 & 1\\
1 & 175 & 20 & 1\\
1 & 180 & 21 & 1\\
1 & 160 & 22 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

and

\begin{bmatrix}
47 \\
68 \\
70 \\
77 \\
52 
\end{bmatrix}

After plugging them into the formula and doing the calculations, I got the following values for c:

c<sub>0</sub> = -137.8333333331393

c<sub>1</sub> = 1.1666666666660603

c<sub>2</sub> = 0.16666666666606034

c<sub>3</sub> = 0.8333333333866904

Then it tells me to write my answer in this form:

```
w = w(h, a, g) =
```

So I typed my answer as this:

```
-137.833 + 1.16667h + 0.166667a + 0.833333g
```

But it is completely wrong. Did I type it in the wrong format? Did I mess up my calculations? Or is it both cases?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Is it the way I typed it? Because I typed it as this: -827/6 + 7/6h + 1/6a + 5/6g

Comment: No dice, it just says the answer is equivalent to the previous one.